# Reverse Percentage Lookup

Tags: math

This must be a simple question but I can't work it out!

I have a number that I know has been reduced to 70% of its original size, how do I find the original number?

For example I have the number 9.1, which is 13 x 70%, but what is the calculation for finding 13?

Comment: A reduction of `70%` of `13` is `13 * (1-0.7) = 3.9`. I think you mean _X_ reduced **by** `30%`, or `70%` **of** _X_. The word **by** or **of** are key to understanding what is going on. Either way reverse this equation `13 * (1-0.7) = 13 * 0.7 = 9.1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want

```
originalNumber = reducedNumber / (percentage / 100);
```

for example

```
13 = 9.1 / (70 / 100)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well if you have some number `x`, you're looking for a `y` so that

```
 y * 70% = x
 y * 70/100 = x
 y = 100 * x / 70
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking your example. 
Say you have an item with `DiscPrice = 9.1` and the discount amount is `Disc = 30%`
and you wanted to calculate the original `SellingPrice' before the discount. Then the equation will be:

```
SellingPrice = ( DiscPrice * 100 ) / ( 100 - Disc )

// in your case then it will be
SellingPrice = ( 9.1 * 100 ) / ( 100 - 30 )
             = 13
```

See it in action:
[image]

The above formulate for the decrease percentage calculation.
There is also an increase percentage calculation here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54125117/850840

Answer (score 0):

Another way to look at this, is you can calculate the inverse percent. Then multiply that by your reduced value to get the original value.

The percent was 70%.

70 percent is actually 70/100.

The inverse of that is 100/70. Because 100/70 * 70/100 = 1.

So, 100/70 (or ~1.42857) times 9.1 = 13.